# Audio not working on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I've installed the `alsa-utils` package. Running `amixer sset Master unmute` returns the error `amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0`.

Executing `alsamixer` gives me the alsamixer application in the teriminal emulator, but `<-` and `->` do nothing; I can only use `m` on an item listed as `S/PDIF`.

`beep` works in the console, but no other audio works.

Any help greatly appreciated.

As per @jasonwryan's request, here's some information regarding my sound card:

```
$cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xe0244000 irq 27
 1 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xe0240000 irq 16
```

---

```
$aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

Meet my `~/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card SB
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card Generic
}
```

---

Verifying correct sound modules are loaded:

```
$lsmod | grep '^snd' | column -t

snd_hda_codec_conexant  21937   1
snd_hda_codec_generic   63087   1  snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_codec_hdmi      49263   1
snd_hda_intel           26387   0
snd_hda_controller      26938   1  snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec           112621  5  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep               17244   1  snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                 88785   4  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer               26614   1  snd_pcm
snd                     73436   8  snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
```

---

```
$ls -l /dev/snd

total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Jan 28 08:15 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Jan 28 08:15 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Jan 28 08:15 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Jan 28 08:15 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Jan 28 08:15 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Jan 28 08:15 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Jan 28 08:15 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Jan 28 08:15 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jan 28 08:15 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jan 28 08:15 timer
```

---

```
$amixer scontrols

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
```

---

A quick look for `asoundrc.txt` as mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Configuration) shows that it DNE on my system

```
$pacman -Ql alsa-lib | grep asound

alsa-lib /usr/include/alsa/asoundef.h
alsa-lib /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h
alsa-lib /usr/include/alsa/sound/asound_fm.h
alsa-lib /usr/include/sys/asoundlib.h
alsa-lib /usr/lib/libasound.so
alsa-lib /usr/lib/libasound.so.2
alsa-lib /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0
```

###############################UPDATE

I've been running Xfce4 as my Desktop Environment, and just recently switched to Gnome.  **All** audio now works.

I'm leaving the thread open in case anybody can figure out ***why*** this should fix the issue. I'd really like to know.

Comment: Please include details of your audio card in your post and the output of the troubleshooting and diagnostic steps on the [Arch Wiki ALSA page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Unmuting_the_channels)...

Answer (score 1):

i had a simiar issue when i was using a display connected with HDMI. 
i manage to fix the sound issue after i created the `.asoundrc` with

```
pcm.!default {
      type hw
      card 1
      device 0
}
ctl.!default {
      type hw
      card 1
}
```

i got the above values from `aplay -l`
And then i run : `alsactl kill rescan`  and `alsactl restore`.
and finaly a `$ reboot`

Comment: deleted `device 0` from ctl because was causing a alsamixer `Invalid argument` error

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for me:

Add to `~/.asoundrc`:

```
pcm.!default {
 type pulse
}
ctl.!default {
 type pulse
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just guess that your sound card works fine and that it is entirely pulseaudio that is to blame. Alsamixer is not compatible with pulseaudio.

Try pavucontrol (or similar tool) that allows you to modify the pulse audio mixer controls.

Comment: "Alsamixer is not compatible with pulseaudio" is factually wrong. And OP has not mentioned installing PA...

Comment: The poster did mention that he installed ALSA which implies that it is not default. Archlinux does install pulse-audio by default thus it is likely to work as a mixer where as ALSA probably will not.

Comment: RThe OP installed `alsa-utils`, there is no need to install ALSA on Arch as it is the default, not PA. Please read the Arch documentation before continuing to post incorrect statements.

Comment: jasonwryan is right, the wiki does state that `alsa-utils` is installed with the `linux` package as part of the base system. I simply reinstalled to be doubly sure that ALSA was definitely present.